# MongoSource from Kafka connect create weird _data key

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm using KafkaConnect - MongoSource with the following configuration:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongo-source2/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "name":"mongo-source2",
  "tasks.max":1,
  "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
  "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "connection.uri":"mongodb://xxx:xxx@localhost:27017/mydb",
  "database":"mydb",
  "collection":"claimmappingrules.66667777-8888-9999-0000-666677770000",
  "pipeline":"[{\"$addFields\": {\"something\":\"xxxx\"} }]",
  "transforms":"dropTopicPrefix",
  "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
  "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":".*",
  "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"my-topic"
}'
```

For some reason, when I consume messages, I'm getting a weird key:

```
 "_id": {
"_data": "825DFD2A53000000012B022C0100296E5A1004060C0FB7484A4990A7363EF5F662CF8D465A5F6964005A1003F9974744D06AFB498EF8D78370B0CD440004"
  }
```

I have no Idea where did it come from, My mongo document's _id is UUID, When I'm consuming messages, I was expected to see the documentKey field at my consumer key.

Here is a message example of what the connector published into kafka:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_data": "825DFD2A53000000012B022C0100296E5A1004060C0FB7484A4990A7363EF5F662CF8D465A5F6964005A1003F9974744D06AFB498EF8D78370B0CD440004"
  },
  "operationType": "replace",
  "clusterTime": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1576872531,
      "i": 1
    }
  },
  "fullDocument": {
    "_id": {
      "$binary": "+ZdHRNBq+0mO+NeDcLDNRA==",
      "$type": "03"
    },
    ...
  },
  "ns": {
    "db": "security",
    "coll": "users"
  },
  "documentKey": {
    "_id": {
      "$binary": "+ZdHRNBq+0mO+NeDcLDNRA==",
      "$type": "03"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter on key.converter and value.converter?

Comment: I tried it now (i also disabled schema for key and value), and got this key (still has weird _data) : ===>  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"_id\": {\"_data\": \"825DFD4132000000012B022C0100296E5A1004060C0FB7484A4990A7363EF5F662CF8D465A5F6964005A1003F9974744D06AFB498EF8D78370B0CD440004\"}}"}

Comment: You say you disabled the schema, but it's there in what you posted. Also that Mongo connector is open source if you want to find out what each field mean

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I'm doing some tests and mistakenly put it with schema. but when I disable schema, I get same result with "_data" just without schema. Mongo stream documentation says they puts this _id -> _data in there, it's a resume token, but the question is, can we easily use the documentKey->id->binary (from above) as the Kafka key? because this is the actual key of the document.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation related to schema for Kafka connect configuration is really limited out there. I know it is too late to reply but lately I have also been facing the same issue and found out the solution by trial and error.

I added these two configuration to my mongodb-kafka-connect configuration -

```
"output.format.key": "schema",
"output.schema.key": "{\"name\":\"sampleId\",\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"com.mongoexchange.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}",
```

But still even after this I don't know whether resume_token of change stream as a key for kafka partition allotment had any significance in term of performance or even for the case where resume_token gets expired due long time of inactivity.

P.S. - The final version of my kafka connect configuration for mongodb as a source is this -

```
{
  "tasks.max": 1,
  "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "connection.uri": "mongodb://example-mongodb-0:27017,example-mongodb-1:27017,example-mongodb-2:27017/?replicaSet=replicaSet",
  "database": "exampleDB",
  "collection": "exampleCollection",
  "output.format.key": "schema",
  "output.schema.key": "{\"name\":\"ClassroomId\",\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"com.mongoexchange.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}",
  "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
  "copy.existing": "true",
  "topic.prefix": "mongodb"
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose "output.format.key": "schema"?
Doesn't the "output.format.key": "json" work as well?